# Using immer can not modify property Number of nested object

Tags: javascript, object, redux, immer.js, redux-reducers

I am using Angular 2+ with Redux and is fine,
but can not modify quantity with the new value

The error is:
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '[object Object]'

```
export interface CartState {
    readonly cars: CartCarModel[]
  }

  export class CartCarModel {
    constructor (
      public carId: string,
      public carModel: string,
      public quantity: number,
      public price: number) { }
  }


  const initialState: CartState = {
    cars: []
  }

  function reducerFunc (state: CartState, id: string, quantity: number) {
    const nextState = produce(state, draft => {
    draft.cars.find(d => d.carId === id).quantity = quantity
  })

  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    drinks: nextState
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because in redux you can't modify the value of the state
u have to copy the values
so use `map`
instead of `find`
and i hope things gose well

Comment: The same error TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'quantity' of object '[object Object]' ``` function reducerFunc(state: CartState, id: string, quantity: number) {
  const nextState = produce(state, draft => {
   draft.cars.map( ops => {

    if (ops.carId === id) {
      return ops.quantity = quantity;
    }
    else { return ops}

  })
})

return Object.assign({}, state, {
  cars: nextState
})
}```

Comment: because u still editing the same reference  u have to clone the object and make return like that 
```
if(ops.carld===id)
 return {...ops,quantity:quantity}
else
 return ops
```

Comment: i just test it but not working, no error and the quentity is the same     if (ops.drinkId === id) {
      return {...ops, quantity: quantity}
    }  I am debuging with chrome and quentity is the same

Comment: i already checked out ur implementation
so i found that u set  readonly cars: CartCarModel[]
try to remove readonly keyword

Comment: https://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-redux-with-typescript-and-angular-2/
check this out ... there is no readonly keyword

Comment: i believe that u has somethings wrong with ur Redux implementation 
please check out the Tutorial that i give u in the previous comment
and let me know if u can't fix it

Comment: its all about ngrx version I downgraded and everything is fine
It was an amazing adventure :)